# Flex Debugger wont launch - Only on particular project

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, debugging

When trying to launch Flex debaugger on my project, it does not launch and I get an error instead. Every other project in different workspaces launches just fine. This is the only one giving me an issue.

Here is the error:

> Process terminated without
>   establishing connection to debugger.
>
> Command:
>
> "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder
>   3\sdks\3.2.0\bin\adl.exe"
>   D:\fromLapTop\lapDocs\Flex\Workspaces\MothersRings\MothersRingsAir\bin-debug\MothersRingsAir-app.xml
>   D:\fromLapTop\lapDocs\Flex\Workspaces\MothersRings\MothersRingsAir\bin-debug
>
> Output from command:
>
> PreloadSwf paths must be local
>   trusted:
>   D:/fromLapTop/lapDocs/Flex/Workspaces/WebRequestNotifier/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999error
>   while loading initial content

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try copying the pre-loadSwf path to C:\ drive too? Just a guess..